# Convert MySql Blob to PDF in react native

Tags: react-native

Hello everyone I have tried many solution to download and preview PDF from a blob in react native
But all in vein. Data is coming from laravel API and  in the form of...

Response from API

[image: 1]

and download file function is this

```html
const downloadFiles = (invoiceNo, personId) => {
  if (!invoiceNo && !personId) return;
  let path =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir
      : RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir;
  let fields = invoiceNo;

  //let fileName = fields[fields.length - 1];
  const configOptions = Platform.select({
    ios: {
      fileCache: true,
      path: `${path}/${fields}.pdf`,
      appendExt: 'pdf',
    },
    android: {
      //fileCache: true,
      useDownloadManager: true,
      notification: true,
      mediaScannable: true,
      mime: 'application/pdf',
      path: `${path}/${fields}.pdf`,
      description: 'File downloaded by download manager.',
    },
  });
  RNFetchBlob.config(configOptions)
    .fetch(
      'GET',
      baseUrl + `downloadInvoice?person_id=${personId}&invoice_id=${invoiceNo}`,
      {},
    )
    .then(res => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        RNFetchBlob.fs.writeFile(`${path}/${fields}.pdf`, res.data, 'base64');
        RNFetchBlob.ios.previewDocument(`${path}/${fields}.pdf`);
      }
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        console.log('The file saved to ', pdfLocation);
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: did you try `react-native-view-pdf`?

Comment: it is not useful in my case

Comment: how do you want to preview the file?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Actually React native need blob data in the form of base-64 and then use this data in your application Like
RNFetchBlob.fs
.writeFile(`${path}/${invoiceNo}.pdf`, downloadFile, 'base64')
.then(res => console.log('File :: ', res))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).